# ARM Neon Assembler - strange pipeline issue

Tags: android, assembly, android-ndk, arm, neon

I am trying to increase the performance of a piece of code written in ARM Assembler using Neon instructions.

For testing and calculating I use this calculator:
http://pulsar.webshaker.net/ccc/sample-706454b3

I noticed that at line "n.34-0   1c n0" suddenly the Neon unit seems to have to wait(?) for 10 cycles. What could be the reason for that or is it just an bug in the calculator?

Also I would need some general information how to improve the performance in ARM/Neon Assembler.

Target is an ARM Cortex-A9.
For compiling I use the newest android-ndk with inline Assembler. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact this is a little bit more complexe.
BitBank Is right, NEON have to wait for D4.

But you have to wait for 10 cycles because Neon have a Load/Store Queue.
And the queue is filled with other instruction before the

```
vld1.64 d4, [r7, :64]
```

So when you need D4, you must wait for the execution of this instruction
but To execute this instruction you must execute all the previous Load/Store instruction pushed into the NEON Load/Store Queue.

Answer (score 3):

The NEON unit has to wait at that instruction because you're referencing a register (D4) which was loaded in the previous NEON instruction (n.33-0   1c n0). Loads are not instantaneous and due to the pipelining, there is a delay in the availability of the data even if it comes from the cache. You need to reorder both your ARM and NEON instructions to not try to use registers immediately after you load them or you will end up with wasted cycles (pipeline stalls).

Comment: those hazards are only 1~2 cycles, if cache hit. In this case, it's something different.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't access memory via ARM while NEON is doing its job. It causes a full brake on NEON.

Apparently, you are trying some kind of parallel processing which is devastating for the reason above.

Besides, there are way too many ldrb's. Byte access on ARM is also almost a sin.

I suggest you completely rewrite your code in C first, with 32 bit only memory accesses, then evaluate whether it is meant to be for NEON at all,

Comment: Thank for the comment. I need only one Byte so if I would read 32Bit at once I need to Shift/ANd the whole thing again and this would be slower. The Code is already there as C & ARM Assembler and I need to check if I can speed it up with Neon instruction. In theory it should be 30-40% faster. Which operations can be done in parallel. ARM arithmetic and Neon load/store but not(?) an Neon arithmetic and an ARM Load/Store?

Comment: You won't believe this: 32bit read +masking is much faster than byte read.

Comment: Forget parallel processing. Moving values from Neon to ARM also results in a pipeline flush wasting 11 cycles. ARM shall serve just as control unit while Neon is doing the whole job.

Comment: I will try loading 32Bit and masking, but I think someone tested it before and it was slower. Okay, thank you for the information. It seems that in my case I can´t increase performance with Neon instructions :-(

Comment: Why don't you try to rewrite your function completely in NEON? Neon is extremely capable doing integer ops, and doesn't require all the time consuming masking ops. If your function contains less than two if-elses within the loop, Neon is the way to go.

Comment: Byte reads' speed may vary depending on SoC. There are some tricks to accelerate masking ops though which makes maskings ALWAYS faster than byte reads on ARM: const unsigned int mask=0xff; byte0=mask&data;byte1=mask&(data>>8);byte2=mask&(data>>16);byte3=mask&(data>>24);

Comment: The trick above benefits from ARM's inline barrel shifter and 1cycle each. You can omit the byte3 masking by inlining it in the desired op, for example: result += (data>>24); Please note that this trick only works in ARM mode since Thumb doesn't support IBS. You should compile all performance critical routines in ARM mode anyway.

Comment: the problem is that most of the time I am calculating adresses (Offset + value shiftes) from which again i load values. If I do the calculation in Neon, again i have to move the resulting adresses to ARM Registers - which is very slow. So I do the calculating part in ARM Assembler and just use Neon to load from the resulting adresses and some XOR. I guess this is not really the use-case foe Neon, but I hope it will bring at least some improvement. Thanks for the infos, I will try Bitmasking. I am aware of the ARM Barrel shifter - so I will tell you if it worked ;-)